# Free Provisioning Profile with Qt

Tags: ios, xcode, qt, xcodebuild

I know that I can use free iOS Provisioning Profile in Xcode (via `Fix Issue` button) for testing. I also know that Qt uses `xcodebuild` for iOS projects. But how can I create and use free Provisioning Profile in the iOS Qt project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your build settings, `qmake` will output an `.xcodeproj` file for you which you can open in Xcode.  Building and running this project on a physical device with your Apple Developer account added under Preferences -> Accounts will cause a development provisioning profile to automatically be generated for your account and app.

Check out the Support for iOS guide [here](https://wiki.qt.io/Support_for_iOS).

Comment: Ok, thanks! It's pretty easy :) but now I get [another error, you can check it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36708016/xcode-failed-with-exit-code-71).