# Xcode failed with exit code 71

Tags: ios, xcode, qt, xcodebuild

I tried to build Qt iOS project but got [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36704293/free-provisioning-profile-with-qt). Now I try to build this project in the Xcode but get this error:

> error: can't exec '/Applications/Xcode' (No such file or directory)
>
> Command /Applications/Xcode failed with exit code 71

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Do you have xcode installed? I'd try to build and deploy a "hello world" from within xcode before moving to Qt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/` and recreating the project helped.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense; you must have mis-used `xcode-select` in the first place?

Comment: @trojanfoe almost: I somehow installed two versions of Xcode, so Qt was configured to another Xcode which was deleted.